# Firebase web authenticate and add to database

Tags: html, web, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am stuck on this and the other posts I have read on here are not useful. So I've reached a point where i need to ask for help after many hours on not resolving what I feel should be a simple task. I program in Swift usually and really know little about html or javasript.

I am building a simple webpage to log-in to Firebase and a second linked page to upload data to a database. Both work fine. The problem is getting the uploaded data to link to the uid of the current user.

So I am logged into an existing user with it's own uid. How do I then upload the data to the current user did in the database? Should be simple but I am just not getting it :-(

Code for uploading data is as follows (note I have tried using both set and push):

```
// Generate a reference to a new location and add some data using push()
var postsRef = ref.child("users");
 var newPostRef = postsRef.push({

//  var newPostRef = postsRef.set({
    name: _name,
    property: _property,

    email: _email,
    phone: _phone,
```

Any help, or better still a working simple example would be useful. I have read the docs on Firebase, so please don't direct me there :-)

Many thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a best practice to create a new database node using the UID generated by the account creation as the path after /users.

Right now, when you push data into /users, Firebase creates a uid for that particular array item that does not correspond to the UID of the user.

If you use set, you need to specify the path you will set which should include the long UI: /users/longGUIDhere

You can get the user id with something like this (from Firebase docs):

```js
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var name, email, photoUrl, uid;

if (user != null) {
  name = user.displayName;
  email = user.email;
  photoUrl = user.photoURL;
  uid = user.uid;  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
                   // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
                   // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
}
```

And then you shouuld use uid to populate the path like below to save their info:

```js
function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
}
```

I know you asked not to be referred to the Firebase docs, but it also looks like you are using an older version of the SDK, so that could be part the issue as well. I recommend taking a look at these two page, since that is where I pulled these verbatim examples: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer which is appreciated. However, I had already seen these examples on the Firebase site and was unable to translate them into a working model :-( I just spent all morning again trying to get this to work. I can get the Uid but am having problems writing it to the database. I feel it should be easy and that I am on the brink of solving it - but it ain't happening :-(

Comment: Can you post your code in a JS Fiddle or code pen? Include all of the relevant JS code

Comment: Hi, I had not come across code pen. Looks useful. I will try and put my code in a 'pen' when I get the chance - it's a bit rough though :-)

Comment: J_Everhart383  I put the html code in a Pen (as I said, it's a bit rough at the moment). You can find it by doing a Search on User for PhilipS. Hope you can help me out here :-)

Comment: I can't find you in the code pen search. You should be able to make it public and put a link here. If you can get me a link, I'm happy to take a look

Comment: Thanks guys. Finally got this to work and of course now do not know how I missed it in the first place. Hindsight! :-) The problem is my lack of knowledge of html / javascript. What seems to have happened is that I was putting the code from the example in the wrong place and not getting the current user UID. n.b in the examples provided above the user.uid is defined as 'uid' in the first part and 'userID' in the second. Caused me a little confusion :-) Now on to the next bit.

Comment: Didn't take long to hit the next problem! I thought that as I was using uid sign in that setting up the rule for authorised read / write would work. It does not at the moment. Will try again but may post it as a question and maybe others have resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var postsRef = ref.child("users/current user id or json key");
```

this will help you to update the details of current user.